# How to save esi or edi in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm performing a couple of processes that already require the use of a source index. If I need to use a source index that's already being used for another item, how can I do that? Is there a way to save edi as data and then retrieve it when necessary?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack is for that:

```
push %esi
push %edi
...
...
...
pop %edi
pop %esi
```

Always pay attention to the order. Also, use the appropiate version of `push`/`pop`.

If you need to save and access different values at the same time, making your own stackframe is a better solution.

Example (at the beginning of the function, AT&T syntax):

```
push %ebp  // save the old ebp
mov %esp, %ebp // ebp now points to the top of the stack
sub X, %ebp // reserve X bytes for the current function
```

Now you can reference memory locations in reference to %ebp, example:

```
movl $1, -4(%ebp) // moves constant 1 to the first free location
movl $1, -8(%ebp) // moves constant 1 to the next free location
addl -4(%ebp), -8(%ebp) // add -4(%ebp) and -8(%ebp) together and write in -8(%ebp)
```

Similiary, you could save your first variable in -4(%ebp) and your second in -8(%ebp).

To the destroy the stackframe and return:

```
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

You don't need to clear the memory, as it'll be overwritten once that space is used again.

Comment: Ok, so would it work somewhat similar to this?
`lea edi,evens
push edi
lea edi,odds
pop edi`
At which point I would just push and pop as necessary to switch between the two?

Comment: After you pushed the value in %edi to the stack, you are free to use the register however you like. You push once you need the register for something different, and pop if you need the value back. However, if you have to switch between both, consider making your own stackframe and use normal memory operation on that.

Comment: The last code snippet here is a bit confusing. It is some kind of mixture of Intel and AT&T syntax (Intel ordering, AT&T syntax). You are also overwriting the saved value of `ebp`. The available space starts *below* it, not *at* it. And you should probably show how to destroy the stack frame too.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw I hope it's correct now. I wrote it in a hurry. Adjusted the syntax as well to be just AT&T (which I'm more familiar with).

Answer (score 3):

A common way to do this is to use the CPU stack:

```
push esi
; ... do whatever needs esi
pop  esi
```

If there's anything in between the `push` and the `pop` that jumps elsewhere, you will have to ensure that the stack is cleaned up appropriately.

Comment: It's not the CPU stack. The stack is in memory.

Comment: It's the stack managed by the CPU and pointed to by the `esp` register. It's the only stack the CPU has, and therefore it's the "CPU stack". Yes, the CPU stack is in memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
push edi

; ... code that uses edi

pop edi
```